# Forest - how to make nodes grow in separate directions

Tags: forest

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\newcommand{\nodecircle}{circle,fill,outer sep=0,inner sep=1pt}

\begin{document}

    \begin{forest}
        [,\nodecircle, alias = I, s sep=0.4cm,l sep=2cm,
        [Rain]
        [Shine]
        ] 
        \node[above] at (I){Nature}; 
    \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

This produces a forest with two nodes, growing downwards.

I know that to change the direction in which it grows, I have to use the `grow = option` command.

<s>However, how do I make both child nodes grow in *separate* directions?</s>

Specifically, I want the first child node to grow east, and the second to grow west.

However, how do I grow in two different directions from the *same parent node*? Specifically, I want the Rain node to be horizontally to the right (i.e `east`) and the Shine node to be `west`.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151042/forest-different-growing-directions-for-branches-on-the-same-level?rq=1) provides an answer which even the person who answered deemed not elegant. I was wondering if there is a newer way to do it.

Comment: There is an example on p. 42 of the `forest` manual.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. Which function am I looking for? Relative nodes?

Comment: I was referring to "make nodes grow in separate directions".

Comment: Apologies, but I don't see which example on [page 42](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/texlive-doc/latex/forest/forest.pdf) deals with this problem.

Comment: ... because you are looking at an older version of the manual.... in the link the example is on p. 30 ...

Comment: @marmot I deeply apologise. I had unintentionally asked a different question than the one I meant to. I have edited the question, with the stupid phrasing struck out.

Comment: Note that the person who answered is the package author ....

Answer (score 2):

This code works (based off Method 1 [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151408/146362)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\newcommand{\nodecircle}{circle,fill,outer sep=0,inner sep=1pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    [,\nodecircle, alias = I, l sep=2cm, grow = east
    [,\nodecircle, before computing xy={l=3cm,s=0cm}, alias = rain]
    [,\nodecircle, before computing xy={l=-3cm,s=0cm}, alias = shine]
    ] 
    \node[above] at (I){Nature}; 
    \node[above] at (rain){Rain}; 
    \node[above] at (shine){Shine}; 
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

More elegant solutions are very welcome.

Comment: If you are going to do this, you might as well either not use `forest` or just set them using `label`, because you're not using Forest to place them at all.

Comment: I was basing this off Saso's answer at the question I linked to. I found this to be a workable solution, since I could grow the rest of my tree easily from here (I have found `forest` the easiest package to work with generally).

If you have a more elegant way to achieve it, I'll happily take it on board, if it has the same ease of use as `forest`.

Comment: Why can't you just say e.g. `[, \nodecirle, label=above:Nature, ...]`?