# Create figures with tikz (frames)

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I was thinking of creating a figure similar to this:
[image: Lexem-Frame]

On first glance, it looked quite doable through tikz

see MWE
but when it comes to styles and refining the figure, I am a bit at a loss

- having the tree grow down and to the right (for "Lesart"),
- having different styles for the "bubbles" (Nomen, maus, Lesart) and "arrows" and arrows ending without bubble
- having different spacing

/On a side note, is there also a way to change fonts for figures to make them more readable?

Would you mind to help here?

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=0.75cm}]
\graph [tree layout, grow=down, fresh nodes, level distance=1in, sibling distance=0.5in]
    {
         Nomen -> { 
          Maus -> {Genus,Numerus,Register,Flex, Lesart 1 -> {" "," "," "}, Lesart 2 -> {" "," "," "}}
        } 
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

---

Updated version that produces the unwanted configuration of arrows stemming from the same place:

```
    \documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FIGURES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
%\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest} % linguistic figures
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,positioning,shapes.symbols,chains}

\forestset{
east branch/.style = {grow=east, child anchor=west,
                      if level = 3{text width=2ex,draw=none,edge=dashed}{}}
          }% end of forestset




\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% node style
    circle,
    draw,
    text width = 4em, text badly centered,
      if level = 2{font=\sffamily\scshape\scriptsize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}
                  {font=\sffamily\itshape\scriptsize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
     inner sep = 1pt,
/tikz/every label/.append style = {align=left, 
    font=\sffamily\scriptsize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
% tree style
    child anchor=north,
    edge = {-{Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}, semithick},
    l sep=12mm,
    s sep=2mm,
           }
% tree body code
[Nomen, double, dashed, label=right: Versuh fuer einem \\
                                     Lexem-Frame fuer \textit{Mause},
    [/maus/, double,
        [Genus              [femin.]]
        [Numerus            [sing.]]
        [Register/\\ Silver [neutral]],
        [Flex.-Klasse   [Sg. I. Pl. S1/U*.,
                         label=right:*Angabe der Flexionklasse hier\\
                                      nach \textsc{Duden-Grammmatic}\textsuperscript{7} 2005
                        ]
        ],
        [Lesart\\ 1,
for tree={east branch},
before computing xy={l=-9mm,s=35mm},
            []  []  []
        ]
        [test\\ 2,
for tree={east branch},
before computing xy={l=+9mm,s=35mm},   
            []  []  []
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One more solution with `forest`.

**Edit (1):**
Slightly improved MWE code by introducing `\forestset` for settings of branches directed to east.

**Edit (2):**
Added `newtxtext` packages that all fonts in nodes can be `sffamily`, corrected text in nodes.

**Edit (3):**
Corrected positioning of text in nodes:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\forestset{
east branch/.style = {grow=east, anchor=center, child anchor=west,
                      if level = 3{text width=2ex,draw=none,edge=dashed}{}}
          }% end of forestset


\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% node style
    circle,
    draw,
    text width = 3.4em, text badly centered,
     inner sep = 1pt,
        anchor = center,
if level = 2{font=\sffamily\scshape\scriptsize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}
            {font=\sffamily\scriptsize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
if level = 3{font=\sffamily\itshape\scriptsize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}{},
/tikz/every label/.append style = {align=left, 
    font=\sffamily\scriptsize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
% tree style
    child anchor=north,
    edge = {-{Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}, semithick},
    l sep=12mm,
    s sep=2mm,
           }
% tree body code
[Nomen, double, dashed, label=right: Versuh fuer einem \\
                                     Lexem-Frame fuer \textit{Mause},
    [/maus/, double,
        [Genus              [femin.]]
        [Numerus            [sing.]]
        [Register/\\ Silver [neutral]],
        [Flex.-Klasse   [Sg. I. Pl. S1/U*.,
                         label=right:*Angabe der Flexionklasse hier\\
                                      nach \textsc{Duden-Grammmatic}\textsuperscript{7} 2005
                        ]
        ],
        [Lesart\\ 1,
for tree={east branch},
before computing xy={l=-9mm,s=35mm},
            []  []  []
        ]
        [Lesart\\ 2,
for tree={east branch},
before computing xy={l=+9mm,s=35mm},   
            []  []  []
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addednum:**
In case that some of yours forest diagram use the `linguistics` library, you can use it on the following way:

- in preamble instead loading `\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}`
  load

  ```
  \usepackage{forest}
  \useforestlibrary{linguistics}
  ```
- when you need to use a `forest` linguistics diagram, then insert `\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}` in local group, for example:

  ```
  \begingroup
  \forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}
  \begin{forest}
  % forest specification
  % linguistics diagram code
  \end{forest}
  \end{group}
  ```

Please consider recent version of my forest code. It is more concise and has improved diagram layout.

Comment: Thank you so much @zarko

Comment: For some reason, it will align all arrow roots at the same spot for mouse [image](https://imgur.com/a/2SC68Lj) when using your example, do you happen to know why?

Comment: @user236381, hm, I cant reproduce your problem. Showed image is produced with MWE in answer (with old and new, slightly improved version). It seems that you add `parent anchor` to my code. Do you really need it?

Comment: I have edited the code with the problem into the main question :)

Comment: @user236381, ah, you use linguistics library. See addendum to my answer (will appear ASAP).  BTW, try to use recent version of MWE in my answer.

Comment: thanks! its perfect now thanks to you! @zarko

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to TeX.SX! Since you already load it, why don't you use the `forest` package:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}

\forestset{
 default preamble={
  for tree={
   circle,
   draw,
   font=\footnotesize,
   edge=->,
   l=25mm,
  }
 },
 eastbound/.style={
  edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}](!u.east)--(.west)\forestoption{edge label};},
  grow=east, 
  ignore,
 },
}

\begin{forest}
 [Nomen, dashed
  [Maus
   [Genus]
   [Numerus]
   [Register]
   [Flex]
   [Lesart 1, before computing xy={l=15mm,s=35mm}, eastbound
    [{},draw=none][{},draw=none][{},draw=none]] 
   [Lesart 2, before computing xy={l=-5mm,s=35mm}, eastbound
    [{},draw=none][{},draw=none][{},draw=none]] 
  ]
 ]
\end{forest}

\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Edit: You can simplify the edge path set-up and automatically process empty nodes:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}

\forestset{
 default preamble={
  for tree={
   circle,
   draw,
   font=\footnotesize,
   edge=->,
   edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}](!u)--()\forestoption{edge label};},
   l=25mm,
  },
  delay={
   where content={}{
    draw=none,
    edge=dashed,
   }{},
  }
 },
}

\begin{forest}
 [Nomen, dashed
  [Maus
   [Genus]
   [Numerus]
   [Register]
   [Flex]
   [Lesart 1, before computing xy={l=15mm,s=35mm}, grow=east, ignore
    [][][]] 
   [Lesart 2, before computing xy={l=-5mm,s=35mm}, grow=east, ignore
    [][][]] 
  ]
 ]
\end{forest}

\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

See also: [Forest: different growing directions for branches on the same level](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151042/47927)

Comment: Thank you so much!