# forest – grow half of tree the other direction

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I am trying to change the growth direction midway while growing my tree with `forest`.
Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{edges}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    forked edges,
    for tree={grow'=east}
    [R
      [1 [a] [b]]
      [2 [c] [d]]
      [3 [e] [f]]
      [4 [g] [h]]
      [5 [i] [j]]
      [6 [k] [l]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: Output of MWE]

**What I would want is for the children `4`, `5`, and `6` of `R` to move over to the left side. So that I would have 3-3 children on each side. Is there a way to do this without hacking the position of child node `3` using `before ...` options? I would like the left side to be symmetrical.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update 2:

A more general solution that wraps this up into a new option called `multiple directions`, which requires no manual placing of nodes [can be found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643061/125871).

### Updated Solution:

After thinking about this some more, I realized that this can be done with no manual tweaking by placing two empty children of `R` at the root using `before computing xy={l=0,s=0}` and setting the `grow` direction of their subtrees. This can be placed into the main `for tree` using `if level=1{<do this>}{<else do this>}`

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={forked edge, minimum height=3.7ex, minimum width=1em, anchor=center,
    if level=1{no edge, before computing xy={l=0,s=0}}{}}
    [R, 
      [, for tree={grow'=east}
        [1 [a] [b]]
        [2 [c] [d]]
        [3 [e] [f]]]
      [, for tree={grow=west}
        [4 [g] [h]]
        [5 [i] [j]]
        [6 [k] [l]]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

### Old Solution:

Unfortunately, `forest` isn't designed to have subtrees `grow` in different directions. There has to be some manual tweaking to make it work. You need the `1`, `2`, `3` nodes to have a different parent than the `4`, `5`, `6` nodes. So give the `R` node two empty children, one that `grow`s west and one that `grow'`s east, and set the `s sep` to 0. Note that you need to set `grow'=south` for the `R` node so that the second subtree (4,5,6) is on the left and the first (1,2,3) is on the right.

Then adjust the position of the `R` node by lowering it into position with `y-=3cm`. To get the nodes in the left subtree aligned with the nodes on the right, all nodes must be the same height, so add `minimum height=3.5ex` to each node.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    grow'=south, for tree={forked edge, minimum height=3.7ex,anchor=center}
    [R, s sep=0cm, before drawing tree={y-=3cm}
      [, for tree={grow'=east}, no edge
        [1 [a] [b]]
        [2 [c] [d]]
        [3 [e] [f]]]
      [, for tree={grow=west}, no edge
        [4 [g] [h]]
        [5 [i] [j]]
        [6 [k] [l]]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your post answers my question, but this has the unpleasant side effect of the tree root R not being in the center vertically (not in line with children 5 and 2). It is frustrating, but it seems that I would be better off drawing this tree (which is more like a mind map) _by hand_, placing nodes and edges.

Comment: @bp99: I edited my response. You just need to add `anchor=center` to the `for tree`. I also increased the `minimum height` to `3.7ex` to make sure there is enough space in the node for the `j`, or any text that dips below the baseline.

Comment: @bp99: I updated my solution (again). It's much simpler and more flexible now, and requires no manual placement of any nodes.

Comment: Very nice, thanks!

Comment: @bp99: Also, take a look at [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643061/125871), which automates the whole process.