# is it possible to make a forest folder to grow both sides?

Tags: diagrams, tikz-trees, forest

I'm trying to save space in diagrams, so I want to know if there's an easy way to make a forest tree folder grow to right and left sides as seen in the image below

[image]

Currently I have this but I've no idea on how to manipulate growing of forest.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows.meta, calc, patterns, patterns.meta, shadows}

\pgfkeys{/forest,
    rect/.append style={rectangle, rounded corners=2pt, /tikz/align=center},
}

\definecolor{background}{RGB}{239, 239, 239}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{RGB}{150, 240, 180}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{146, 208, 80}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{4, 121, 181}
\definecolor{linecol}{RGB}{92, 92, 92}
\definecolor{lightpink}{RGB}{245, 160, 240}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{176, 221, 255}
\definecolor{lilac}{RGB}{174, 182, 211}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={
            line width=0.5pt,
            draw=linecol,
            rect,
            calign=center,
            minimum size=25pt,
            text width=50mm,
            rounded corners=5pt,
            child anchor=north,
            parent anchor=south,
            drop shadow,
            l sep+=12.5pt,
            inner color=background,
            anchor=center,
            edge path={
                \noexpand\path[color=linecol, rounded corners=5pt,>={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=0.5pt, ->, \forestoption{edge}]
                (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -|
                (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
            if = {level == 1}{outer color=lightblue, text width=38mm}{},
            if = {level == 2}{
                outer color=lightgreen,
                for tree = {
                    text width=28mm,
                    child anchor=west
                }
            }{},
            if = {level == 3}{outer color=lightpink, text width=12mm,}{}
        }
        [Clasificación, outer color=lilac,
        for tree = {
            for children = {
                grow'=0,
                folder
            }
        }
            [Térmicos
                [Adición
                    [MSF][MED][MVC][HDH][SD]
                ]
                [Extracción [Frz]]
            ]
            [Membrana
                [RO][FO][ED][NF]
            ]
            [Químicos
                [I.Ex][LLE][G. Hyd][Otros]
            ]
            [Adsorción]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

I think the solution could lie in the use of:

```tex
for children = {
    if={mod(n,2)==0}{circle}{}
}
```

But it doesn't appear to change when I use `grow'=east` nor `grow'=west`

```tex
[Adición,
    for children = {
        if={mod(n,2)==0}{
            for parent = {grow'=west}
        }{
            for parent = {grow'=east}
        }
    }
    [MSF][MED][MVC][HDH][SD]
]
```

[image]

<sub><sup>And if it's possible, how to center "clasificación"</sup></sub>

Comment: I have found interesting answers to this problem: [Forest: different growing directions for branches on the same level](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151042/forest-different-growing-directions-for-branches-on-the-same-level/643061#643061) and [forest – grow half of tree the other direction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642450/forest-grow-half-of-tree-the-other-direction)

Comment: Did one of those answer your question and we should close as a duplicate? Or is there something remaining? (Or do you not remember by now!?)

Comment: @cfr I couldn't make it work

Comment: You can't have 2 growth directions for the same node. You have to fake it, if I remember correctly. There isn't a *straightforward* way that I know of, so it depends how much trouble you're prepared to go to to save space. I can show you a way to do it, if you want, but it may have unexpected results in other cases, for example, because `forest` may not know where things are.

Comment: I think the `multiple directions` code could work if you're careful. Or you could create the smaller side elsewhere and then move it into position later.

Comment: Just wondering why you allow so much width for the non-red boxes, if space is the issue, which probably is limited in horizontal direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed that Sašo Živanović commented that one post contained the cleanest `forest` code on this site. This one certainly contains the filthiest. It uses an extremely mangled version of [Sašo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/691730/). The mangling is partly a result of my not understanding the purpose of code and partly a product of my inability to modify it appropriately.

If it weren't for the fact nobody has answered this in well over a year, this answer would certainly be worthy of deletion. As it is, it surely deserves no better fate.

[image: pretty product; filthy code]

I've not drawn edges to the `phantom children`. Instead, I've modified their children's edges to draw from their grandparent. But something is very wrong with the way I've configured those children, since --- despite Sašo's positioning code, I still end up having to move them in `before computing xy`. Not only does this mean they are not accounted for when packing; all I've done is hard-code adjustments with no attempt to calculate anything because I don't understand why they end up where they do in the first place.

For what it's worth, I created a test document with a simple tree repeated over and over to experiment with different combinations of `folder`, `grow`/`grow'`/`folder indent`/`l sep` etc., but I still don't understand how to sensibly code a directory tree with the edge to the right of the children and a downward direction of growth. `for tree={folder,grow=180}` seems to work, so I used that, but `dir subtree, grow subtree=180` did not produce similar results. This aspect of `forest` is simply beyond my ability to comprehend it.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=20cm,tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows,ext.paths.ortho}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/705346/
% addaswyd o ateb Sašo Živanović: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/691730/
% addaswyd o gwestiwn Datboi: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/691576/
\forestset{
  declare boolean={phantom child}{0},
  dir subtree/.style={%
    for tree={
      folder,
    },
    for descendants={
      edge path'/.expanded={
        (!uu.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)
      },
    },
  },
  phantom children/.style={
    delay={
      for children={
        content/.option=!u.content,
        opacity=0,
        text opacity=0,
        draw,
        no edge,
        phantom child,
      },
    },
    after packing node={
      for children={
        l'=0pt,
        s'=0pt,
        get point anchor={\foresteoption{grow}+180}{l-}{s-},
      },
    },
  },
  grow subtree/.style={
    for tree={grow=#1}
  }, 
  grow' subtree/.style={
    for tree={grow'=#1}
  },
}

\makeatletter
% Analogous to \pgfpointanchor, but also allows forest anchors ("parent first"
% etc.)  and forest anchor options ("parent anchor" etc.) as #1.
\def\forestpointanchor#1{% #1 = anchor
  \forestanchortotikzanchor{#1}\forest@temp@anchor
  \forestoifdefined{@box}{%
    \forestoget{@box}\forest@temp
    \ifdefempty\forest@temp{%
      \forestpointanchor@callpgfpointanchor{name}%
    }{%
      \setbox0\hbox{%
        \begin{pgfpicture}%
          \forestpointanchor@callpgfpointanchor{later@name}%
        \end{pgfpicture}%
      }%
    }%
  }{%
    \forestpointanchor@callpgfpointanchor{name}%
  }%
  \forest@global@marshal
}
\def\forestpointanchor@callpgfpointanchor#1{% #1 = (later@)name
  \pgfpointanchor{\forestove{#1}}{\forest@temp@anchor}%
  \xdef\forest@global@marshal{%
    \global\pgf@x=\the\pgf@x\relax
    \global\pgf@y=\the\pgf@y\relax\relax
  }%
}
\csdef{forest@anchor@@}{\def\forest@temp@anchor{center}}%
\def\forestPointanchor#1#2{% #1 = node id, #2 = anchor
  \forest@fornode{#1}{\forestpointanchor{#2}}%
}
\forestset{
  % Get the coordinates of anchor #1
  % and assign the resulting x and y to keys #2 and #3, respectively.
  get point anchor/.code n args=3{%
    \forestpointanchor{#1}%
    \forestset{#2=\pgf@x,#3=\pgf@y}%
  },
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% cwestiwn Eduardo Jiménez:https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/650323/
\pgfkeys{/forest,
    rect/.append style={rectangle, rounded corners=5pt, /tikz/align=center},
    level outer colour/.style={outer color={level #1 outer colour}},
}

\definecolor{background}{RGB}{239, 239, 239}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{RGB}{150, 240, 180}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{146, 208, 80}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{4, 121, 181}
\definecolor{linecol}{RGB}{92, 92, 92}
\definecolor{lightpink}{RGB}{245, 160, 240}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{176, 221, 255}
\definecolor{lilac}{RGB}{174, 182, 211}
\colorlet{level 0 outer colour}{lilac}
\colorlet{level 1 outer colour}{lightblue}
\colorlet{level 2 outer colour}{lightgreen}
\colorlet{level 3 outer colour}{lightpink}
\colorlet{level 4 outer colour}{lightpink}
\begin{forest}
  fork sep'=5pt,
  text width=50mm,
  for tree={
    rect,
    line width=0.5pt,
    draw=linecol,
    l sep'+=12.5pt,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    where phantom child={%
    }{%
      level outer colour/.option=level,
      inner color=background,
      drop shadow,
      minimum size=25pt,
    },
  },
  for children={%
    text width=38mm,
    edge+={color=linecol, rounded corners=5pt,-{Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=0.5pt},
    forked edge,
    for tree={%
      grow'=0,
      folder,
      if level=2{%
        text width=28mm,
      }{%
        if level=3{%
          text width=12mm,
        }{},
      },
    },
  },
  [Clasificación
      [Térmicos
        [Adición, phantom children,parent anchor=south
        [, dir subtree,for children={before computing xy={l'+=30pt}}
              [MSF][MED][MVC]
            ]
            [, dir subtree, grow subtree=180,for children={before computing xy={l'-=100pt}}
              [HDH][SD]
            ]
          ]
          [Extracción [Frz]]
      ]
      [,phantom,coordinate,calign with current]
      [Membrana
          [RO][FO][ED][NF]
      ]
      [Químicos
          [I.Ex][LLE][G. Hyd][Otros]
      ]
      [Adsorción]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```